# Как оптимизировать?

Tags: delphi, оптимизация

```
h_n:=2000; w_n:=2000;
y_0:=-20;
y_1:=20;

for y:=1 to h_n  do
 for x:=1 to w_n   do
   begin
     count:=0;
     cl_r:=0;
     cl_g:=0;
     cl_b:=0;
     cl_a:=0;
     for y_y:=y_0 to y_1 do
      begin         
          count:=count+1;
          cl_r:=cl_r+temp_I[x,y_y+y].r;
          cl_g:=cl_g+temp_I[x,y_y+y].g;
          cl_b:=cl_b+temp_I[x,y_y+y].b;
          cl_a:=cl_a+temp_I[x,y_y+y].a;         
      end;
     temp[x,y].r:=round(cl_r/count);
     temp[x,y].g:=round(cl_g/count);
     temp[x,y].b:=round(cl_b/count);
     temp[x,y].a:=round(cl_a/count);
   end;
```

Comment: Например так:

    temp[x,y].r:=cl_r div count;

и count:=count+1; убрать из цикла, а сделать count:=y_1-y0+1;

Comment: Ок. А ещё?

Comment: Да тут особо то и нечего оптимизировать. У вас тут 1.6*10^8, это в любом случае не сильно быстро будет работать

Comment: Если cl_r, cl_g, cl_b, cl_a - это байтовые переменные, то можно их обнулять, поместить в их в структуру, а потом по адресу структуры записывать четырехбайтовый 0 (на си это можно было бы сделать через union, в delphi тоже есть что-то похожее: [записи с вариантами](www.delphicode.org/delphi/records.htm)).

Возможно еще немножко оптимизировать если сделать так:

    with temp[x,y_y+y] do
    begin
    cl_r:=cl_r+r;
    cl_g:=cl_g+g;
    cl_b:=cl_b+b;
    cl_a:=cl_a+a;
    end;

Станет ли от этого сильно лучше я не знаю. Нужно смотреть результат компиляции.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил адресацию к массиву темп и структуре через pointer, ещё можно переписать целиком на асм с использованием SSE

Comment: А если переписать с использованием SSE, будет ли приложение гарантировано работать на вех процессорах?

Comment: Может распараллелить? Разделить матрицу temp_I на 4-ре части, и обрабатывать каждую чать в отдельном потоке?

Comment: А какая целевая база процессоров? Первое SSE держат процы уже лет десять как почти все. Там вроде после pentinum II уже все конкуренты подтянулись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Во первых в программе ошибка: y_y+y будет выходить за границы массива temp_I.
2. Вообще это называется сумма по скользящему окну и известно более эффективное решение.
   Заметьте что для следующего элемента temp[x,y] к окну присоединяется один новый элемент temp_I[y_y+y_1] и уходит один старый temp_I[y_y+y_0-1], итого вместо 40 сложений достаточно одного сложения и одного вычитания.
3. По сравнению с этим избавиться от 0 как начального значения - это мелочь хотя тоже оптимизация.

Comment: Ок. А как насчёт распараллеливования?

Comment: Внутренний цикл становится зависимым от предыдущей итерации,
распараллеливание по внешнему циклу - возможно.
Что хотите использовать для распараллеливания и сколько у вас процессоров?

Comment: Пишу программу на 4-ёх-ядерном intel, но работать программа, желательно, должна и на одноядерном intel. Так что будем считать, что один. А распараллелить я предлагаю так: разделить матрицу temp_I на 4-ре части, и обрабатывать каждую чать в отдельном потоке. Параллелизм конечно не истинный, псевдопараллелизм на одном процессоре.

Comment: Если бы использовали gcc, простое решение в данном случае было бы #pragma omp .

Comment: Да, но мне нужно исходить из того, что у меня процессор одноядерный. Ведь программа должна работать не на моём компьютере. И даже на моём Intel core i3 выполняется 2 - 3 сек. , а должно <1сек

Comment: На одноядерном быстрее будет если не распараллеливать. Можно с векторными командами попробовать, у вас ведь по сути векторы из 4х элементов.
Ещё вариант - хранить данные пиксела в одном 64-разрядном целом, будет по 16 битов на цвет. Складывать такие пикселы можно одной командой на 64-разрядном процессоре, но вот делить сложнее.

Comment: @sercxjo, На одноядерном быстрее будет если не распараллеливать? 0_o Почему это? Вы уверены?

Comment: @ололо Да, добавляются накладные расходы на переключение между процессами. Перезаполняются регистры, сбрасывается кэш. Если есть гипертред, то может быть небольшой выигрыш при условии, что один процесс будет считать в целых числах а другой в вещественных.